# How to include an angular view in another view with the same controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can you put a number of "child" views into a "parent" view in Angular 1? I think it is related to "[Multiple Name Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)" with UI Router, but I don't see a way to specify the parent view. (The example in that link assumes that all the containers are in the *index.html*.)

Here's a simplified example:

```
$stateProvider.state('frame', {
    url: '/frame',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
}).state('frame.page', {
    url: '/frame/page',
    controller: 'page-controller',
    templateUrl: 'views/page.html', // see below
    views: {
        aside: {
           templateUrl: 'views/page-aside.html'
        },
        thing: {
           templateUrl: 'views/page-thing.html'
        }
    }
}) // ... etc ... lots of other states built off of "frame"
```

Where *page.html* contains a lot of content, including some containers for the children views:

```
<div ui-view="aside"></div>
<div ui-view="thing"></div>
```

Comment: I think what you need is a nested state https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: Perhaps if you target the views properly per state like `view: 'aside@frame.page': {...`

Comment: @yBrodsky - From the docs the nested state doesn't seem to allow multiple views. _"Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view."_

Comment: Here you have an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/0d0Le1VdtHIg3Q4bm5il?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @yBrodsky... that almost works, except that it requires the path to be at `/home/sub` rather than `/home`. Any way to do this without abstract states and with the `/home` url?

Comment: I dont think so, I think this is the way to go. The url can be whatever you want of course. https://plnkr.co/edit/2Sd4bTR62IpXCiSDoCIb?p=preview

Comment: Sadly this is not working for me. Something with the controller, params, etc. - probably out of scope for this particular question. I ended up using `ng-include` since I didn't immediately need a new controller for each view.

Answer (score 0):

You use multiple views when you need to control multiples outlets for a state, if you want to change the aside on each of your states, for example.

You can't do the way you suggested because `ui-router` doesn't allow you to use template when using views, because it affects the parent state. The current state represents the configuration of each view (either multiple or single `<div ui-view/>`.

The available solution is to use nested states of the state which contains the `ui-view="myView"` declared. And each sub state will set all the views on the parent set.

The snippet bellow implements a simple nav / section / aside layout with two states implementing multiple view control.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/frame/page/thing');

    $stateProvider
      .state('frame', {
        url: '/frame',
        template: `
          <div ui-view></div>
        `,
      }).state('frame.page', {
        url: '/page',
        template: `
          <nav>
            <a ui-sref="frame.page.thing" ui-sref-active="active">Things</a>
            <a ui-sref="frame.page.stuff" ui-sref-active="active">Stuff</a>
          </nav>
          <section ui-view="thing"></section>
          <aside ui-view="aside"></aside>
        `,
      }).state('frame.page.thing', {
        url: '/thing',
        views: {
          aside: {
            template: `
              <h2>Aside</h2>
              Aside for things
            `
          },
          thing: {
            template: `
              <h2>Page things</h2>
            `
          }
        }
      })
      .state('frame.page.stuff', {
        url: '/thing',
        views: {
          aside: {
            template: `
              <h2>Aside</h2>
              Aside for stuff
            `
          },
          thing: {
            template: `
              <h2>Page Stuff</h2>
            `
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

nav a.active {
  color: blue;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

section,
aside {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
}

section {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```